# need to place 5 divs side by side within footer

Tags: html, css

I need to place 5 DIVs within footer side by side, the 4 DIVs are already side by side but the 5th one just goes down and it is not displayed in my desired location..

I tried `float : left,` `display :inline-block` and even increased the width of parent DIV (footer) but the 5th one stayed below

Here's the code of `HTML` and `CSS` that I Used in my project:

```css
#footer {
  width: 1240px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-image: url(../images/botm.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center top;
}

.Aboutus {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  background-image: url(../images/footer.jpg);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.ourblog {
  float: left;
  width: 245px;
  min-height: 246px;
  background-image: url(../images/footer.jpg);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.joinnews {
  float: left;
  width: 190px;
  min-height: 246px;
  background-image: url(../images/footer.jpg);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.contactus {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 246px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.Histats {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 1px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="aboutus">
    ..code </div>
  <div class="ourblog">
    ..code </div>
  <div class="joinnews">
    ..code </div>
  <div class="contactus">
    ..code </div>
  <div class="Histats">
    ..code </div>
</div>
```

Comment: would it be possible for you to create a fiddle or share a working link with error?

Comment: wait it's still in localhost but i can edit the online one

Comment: You have capitalized the class `Aboutus` in your markup, while it's all lowercase in your css. Best practice is to adopt a convention and stick to it. I personally never use caps in variables or attributes.

Comment: corrected the aboutus class but still no different

strange thought when I create it jsfiddle it works
https://jsfiddle.net/tvsoso1e/

but not in my website

sorry I can't edit the online web until I got it to work on localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:flex`. Check below snippet, this might help to get started.

```css
#footer {
  display: flex;
  width: 1240px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-image: url(../images/botm.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center top;
}
.aboutus {
  width: 180px;
  background-image: url(../images/footer.jpg);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.ourblog {
  width: 245px;
  min-height: 246px;
  background-image: url(../images/footer.jpg);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.joinnews {
  width: 190px;
  min-height: 246px;
  background-image: url(../images/footer.jpg);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.contactus {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 246px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.histats {
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="aboutus">
    ..aboutus
  </div>
  <div class="ourblog">
    ..ourblog
  </div>
  <div class="joinnews">
    ..joinnews
  </div>
  <div class="contactus">
    ..contactus
  </div>
  <div class="histats">
    ..histats
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thank you display : flex; works

I didn't know about this

Answer (score 3):

You css `class` used in `HTML` vs `CSS` doesn't match.

You've used `Aboutus` in CSS while `aboutus` in html as follows:

```
<div class="aboutus">
..code </div>
```

Make both of them same and your css will work.

```css
#footer {
    width:1240px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-image:url(../images/botm.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-position:center top;
}

.aboutus {
    float:left;
    width:180px;
    background-image:url(../images/footer.jpg);
    background-position:right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.ourblog {
    float:left;
    width:245px;
    min-height:246px;
    background-image:url(../images/footer.jpg);
    background-position:right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.joinnews {
    float:left;
    width:190px;
    min-height:246px;
    background-image:url(../images/footer.jpg);
    background-position:right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.contactus {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    min-height:246px;
    color:#fff;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.histats {
    float : left;
    width:50px;
    min-height:1px;
    color:#fff;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
<div class="aboutus">
  ..code </div>
 <div class="ourblog">
  ..code </div>
  <div class="joinnews">
  ..code </div>
 <div class="contactus">
 ..code </div>
  <div class="histats">
 ..code </div>

   </div>
```

Comment: corrected that aboutus class but still no different

Comment: @Citra45Abadi I've updated my answer, All your 5 columns are in one line

Answer (score 1):

use `display: flex` to the parent div.

here is the working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f7jgweny/) for your problem

Answer (score 1):

try to make the width of the div including your 5 divs bigger. It could be that your 4th div hasn't enough space so it goes down.

Answer (score 1):

Your class for "aboutus" section is not match in HTML and CSS

```
<div class="aboutus">
..code </div>

CSS:

.aboutus {}
```

Always make both same in HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

use this -

for footer - use in place of width:1240px;

width:100%;

and in every div make - divide by 5, so it will be 20% for all

width:20%;

hope this will work

Answer (score 1):

Use this structure, and add `float:right` in `.Histats & .contactus`

```css
.clear{clear: both;}
```

```html
    <div id="footer">
     <div class="Histats">a</div>
     <div class="contactus">contact</div>
     <div class="Aboutus">about</div>
     <div class="ourblog">blog</div>
     <div class="joinnews">news</div><div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

add this in **CSS:**

```
.clear{clear: both;}
```